# MonadError typeclass instance for WriterTXorT monad transformer in Cats

Tags: scala, monad-transformers, scala-cats

The `XorT` monad transformer inherits from `MonadError` which exposes error handling functionality. I want to create an instance of the `MonadError` type class for `WriterT[XorT ...]` but I am failing to implement the `handleErrorWith` method.

```
type WriterValid[L, E, T] = WriterT[XorT[Id, E, ?], L, ?]
val writerValidMonad = new MonadError[WriterValid[L, E, ?], E] {
  private val monadT = data.WriterT.writerTMonad[XorT[Id, E, ?], L]

  def raiseError[A](e: E): WriterValid[L, E, A] =
    cats.data.WriterT[Valid[E,?],L,A](validMonad.raiseError[(L,A)](e))

  def handleErrorWith[A](fa: WriterValid[L, E, A])(f: (E) => WriterValid[L, E, A]): WriterValid[L, E, A] =
    ???

  def pure[A](x: A): WriterValid[L, E, A] =
    monadT.pure(x)

  def flatMap[A, B](fa: WriterValid[L, E, A])(f: (A) => WriterValid[L, E, B]): WriterValid[L, E, B] =
    monadT.flatMap(fa)(f)
}
```

Is this something that can be done easily? Also is this the best approach to creating a `MonadError` instance?

Comment: There's [an open PR](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/689) with some discussion about exactly this question (with an implementation).

Comment: That would do it. The whole 'private[data] sealed' is a real hinderance though

Comment: @TravisBrown do you know if there's a generalised trait (like MonadError does for errors) for Injecting an L value into a writer. Ie could work with ReaderTWriter